# How to sum items from csv files from a for loop

Tags: python, loops, csv, sum

I am stuck. My script asks for how many csv files a user wants to enter and by what field. In this case lets say two csv files each with a area value. I am trying to sum up the two items with a for loop so i can then try to write a function that computes average. Ever time i run it though i get an error saying that "unsupported operand type(s) for +: int and str. I'v hit a brick wall. Any help appreciated

```
import csv
Mysum = 0
input_attribute = input("Enter attribute for comparison (lowercase) :")
input_SetNum = input("How many data sets are you comparing: ")
print ("You entered " + input_SetNum) 

data_sets = {}
for i in range(1, int(input_SetNum)+1):
  with open(input("Please enter the file name with .csv: ")) as csvfile:
      reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
      for row in reader:
      data_sets[i] = (row[input_attribute])
      print (data_sets[i])


Mysum = sum(data_sets[i])
print(Mysum)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read a number in from a CSV file, it reads in as a string, unless you do the following:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
```

This has bitten me a few times.

The answer is either to create your `reader` as `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`, or to explicitly convert from `str` to `int` with `int()`.  Without seeing an actual sample of your data files in order to see how they're formatted, it's difficult to say which is the better route to go.

Also, please note that you've still got some formatting issues, like in the previous iterations of your question:

```
import csv
Mysum = 0
input_attribute = input("Enter attribute for comparison (lowercase) :")
input_SetNum = input("How many data sets are you comparing: ")
print ("You entered " + input_SetNum) 

data_sets = {}
for i in range(1, int(input_SetNum)+1):
  with open(input("Please enter the file name with .csv: ")) as csvfile:
      reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
      for row in reader:  # The code in your `for` block needs to be indented or you're going to get more errors...
          data_sets[i] = (row[input_attribute])
          print (data_sets[i])


Mysum = sum(data_sets[i])
print(Mysum)
```

Comment: the data files are very simply they are both just have area and one cell value each.

Comment: Do they have headers?  If not, then you probably don't want to use `csv.DictReader()`, you'd probably want to use `csv.reader()`.

Comment: Yes they have headers depicting what field it is.

Comment: got it to work by changing by writing Mysum = Mysum +int(data_sets[i]) thank you for your help though

Comment: That makes sense -- you did an explicit conversion to `int`.  Opening your reader with `csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` would've converted it to `float` and allowed you to add them as well.